# Resolving dependencies using an external DI container in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 to build a plugin for an existing application (as opposed to a standalone web-app). This existing application has a global DI container with a lot of services already configured, which I can use in my app (named `_externalContainer` in the example). I would like to be able to use some of those services in filters/middlewares/controllers/etc. inside my ASP.NET Core plugin.

However, currently the only way to do that is to explicitly pass all services inside a callback:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
    .ConfigureServices(x =>
    {
        x.AddSingleton(_externalContainer.Resolve<IServiceA>());
        x.AddSingleton(_externalContainer.Resolve<IServiceB>());
        // many more lines like this
    });
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Something along the lines of "if the service is unknown to ASP.NET's internal DI container, delegate resolution to `_externalContainer`".

N.B. The `_externalContainer` does not provide a total list of registered types, so it is not possible to iterate over them.

Comment: Where those services are coming form? Is it some library or NuGet package?

Comment: I did just such a thing for MEF integration with ASP.NET’s DI (and it’s actually “bi-directional”, the MEF container can resolve dependencies from ASP’s container too): https://github.com/davidmilligan/System.Composition.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: Can you please tell us what `_externalContainer` is, and what the current application is? Is the current Application `Asp.Net`? or is it `.Net Core`?

Comment: External application is just a .NET Core console app. The `_externalContainer` is a DI container from that app that I can use in my plugin to create services. I updated the question with some clarification.

Comment: I think the important thing is specifically which DI library are you using in the console app? The author may already have Asp.Net DI integration, perhaps in a separate NuGet. This is the case for e.g. Autofac. If no existing adapter exists, while still possible, the amount of code necessary to implement this is somewhat extensive, at the very least beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: @DaveM I actually expected a framework-agnostic way. For example, Mediatr allows you to specify a delegate like `Func<Type, object>` that lets you plug in any DI engine you use.

Comment: No, every DI container is different and resolves dependencies differently, manages scopes and lifetimes differently, typically have different API shapes and surfaces, implements different interfaces, and has different extension points that work differently. Some DI containers use such fundamentally different paradigms that they are basically incompatible, or are extremely inefficient to try to use together.